# What is a Quotidian Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word™/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+phrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Word%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

It seems that it's a rite of passage on PSE to make at least one of these, so if a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Quotidian Word™.

Use the examples below to find the rule. The order of clues doesn't matter, and the pairings of Quotidian Words™ and Not Quotidian Words™ don't convey any additional information.

| Quotidian Words™ | Not Quotidian Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| arch | arc |
| ding | beep |
| end | finish |
| gate | door |
| goose | moose |
| in | inside |
| ire | rage |
| key | nail |
| lock | hammer |
| rise | risen |
| screen | scan |
| stroke | touch |
| sky | sea |

CSV Version:

```
Quotidian Words™,Not Quotidian Words™
arch,arc
ding,beep
end,finish
gate,door
goose,moose
in,inside
ire,rage
key,nail
lock,hammer
rise,risen
screen,scan
stroke,touch
sky,sea
```

These are not the only examples of Quotidian Words™, many more exist.

Comment: I'll preemptively say that having "key" and "lock" in the same column is not a mistake.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A Quotidian Word™ is one which you can

> prefix a day of the week to produce another word.

The examples are

> Monarch
>  Wedding
>  Friend
>  Frigate
>  Mongoose
>  Satin
>  Satire
>  Monkey
>  Wedlock
>  Sunrise
>  Sunscreen
>  Sunstroke
>  Frisky

Comment: Quotidian, meaning 'daily' also fits. Nice work.